# How does the number of strongly connected components of a graph change when adding one edge?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I'm doing an online course which contains the following multiple-choice question:

[image]

I'm wavering here because both the first and the second answer seem correct. As explained in the answer to Cormen et al., *Introduction to Algorithms*, problem 22.5-1 ([here](http://student.csuci.edu/~douglas.holmes253/Assignment6.html); note that there is a typo, "increased" should be "decreased" in the second point), an added edge can be either between nodes of an existing SCC, thereby not changing the number of SCCs, or can connect two SCCs such that they are 'fuzed' into one. In either case, however, I don't see how the number of SCCs can decrease by more than 1.

Am I missing something? What is the correct answer to this question?

Answer (score 5):

Consider a directed graph with a number of strong connected components, where the [condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component#Definitions) of that graph (each strongly-connected component is reduced to a single vertex) forms a directed path. Then adding an edge to complete a cycle from the last component on the path to the first will make all those components into one strongly-connected component, meaning that an added edge can reduce the number of strongly-connected components by any amount.

---

As a matter of multiple-choice tactics, though, the first answer is clearly true (and it is a badly-written question because of that).

Comment: Well, the first option isn't _trivially_ true, although any non-complete, strongly connected graph is a clear example that it doesn't have to change, so it is rather easy.

Comment: The other reason the question is badly set is because the second answer always implies the third answer is also true (no matter what the question says). So the second answer cannot be the correct selection.